# Typescript generic function so that type inference and code hints will work

Tags: typescript

This is the function call I need to define in Typescript

```
gen(settings: ISettings, enabled?: object, maps?: object): (v: string) => string;
```

Where settings are:

```
interface ISettings {
    mods: string[];
    states: string[];
}
```

But the array values in the `ISettings` are actually related to the other two parameters in the function call: `enabled` and `map`.

Maybe an example would be better understood.

```
gen({
        mods: ['one', 'two'],
        states: ['init', 'final']
    }, {
        one: true,
        init: true
    }, {
        one: 'first',
        two: 'second',
        final: 'end'
    }
);
```

So as you can see:

- the items of arrays in the first object represent object keys for the second and third parameters objects which are partial of those keys
- the second object uses the subset of array keys and values are boolean
- the third object uses the subset of array keys and values are string

This is as far as I got the code, but it's not working. I would like code completion to suggest object keys in the second and third parameter objects, because they're related to those arrays in the first parameter object.

```
interface ISettings<TMods extends object, TStates extends object> {
    mods: Array<keyof TMods & string>;
    states: Array<keyof TStates & string>;
    [other: string]: any;
}

function gen<
    TMods extends object = {},
    TStates extends object = {}
>(
    settings: string | ISettings<TMods, TStates>,
    enabled: Partial<Record<keyof (TMods & TStates), boolean>> = {},
    maps: Partial<Record<keyof (TMods & TStates), string>> = {}
): string {
    //function doesn't return anything yet
    return '';
}

gen({
    mods: ['one', 'two'],
    states: ['disabled', 'fixed']
}, {
    one: true,
    disabled: true
}, {
    one: 'first',
    two: 'second',
    fixed: 'static'
});
```

As can be seen by by proposed types, the `enabled` and `maps` parameters can define any subset (or full) of members of the combination of both string arrays provided in the `settings` object. The two objects can have overlapping members.

```
Partial<Record<keyof (TMods & TStates), ...>>
```

- the `settings` parameter defines the possible object members, but they're split into two string arrays because they are used differently within the function body
- the `enabled` object sets certain members *on*
- the `maps` object changes their names for the output (remaps the original names); the output will only return and remap those that have the enabled flag on.

> ***Note***: this code is basically trying to define the code for the `suit-cx.d.ts` and `bem-classnames.d.ts` files of the npm libs of the same name if you're familiar with them.

Comment: It's unclear to me, the first second and third object can use any subset of the keys from the first object ? Or is there some other rule to it. Can the keys be reused between the second and third object. Must all keys be used  ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir; The `enabled` (second func param) and `maps` (third func param) can define a [full|sub]set of keys defined by both string arrays in the first func object param (`settings`). I've changed the code a tiny bit to reflect this as they now both set a common member (`one`). So **yes**, they can define any subset of members based on both arrays, but none outside of those defined by the two string arrays. Hence their type is `Partial<Record<keyof (TMods & TStates), ...>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying the types a little so that the compiler only has to infer the keys as string literal types (not as keys to another unknown object) lets the compiler help out with suggestions when writing the second and third parameters:

```
interface ISettings<TModsKeys extends string, TStatesKeys extends string> {
    mods: Array<TModsKeys>;
    states: Array<TStatesKeys>;
    [other: string]: any;
}

function gen<
    TModsKeys extends string,
    TStatesKeys extends string
>(
    settings: string | ISettings<TModsKeys, TStatesKeys>,
    enabled: Partial<Record<TModsKeys | TStatesKeys, boolean>> = {},
    maps: Partial<Record<TModsKeys | TStatesKeys, string>> = {}
): string {
    //function doesn't return anything yet
    return '';
}

gen({
    mods: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    states: ['disabled', 'fixed']
}, {
    one: true,
    disabled: true,
}, {
    one: 'first',
    two: 'second',
    fixed: 'static',
});
```

Comment: Oh great! That's exactly how it should work! I've always thought of **Intersection** and **Union** types as boolean logic, so `&` combines all members while `|` chooses between one or the other. But it's not that way as you've correctly cleaned this code.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik they are similar, `&` means that a type is both members types at the same type, while `|` means the type can be either member type. The reason why `|` is used for keys has to do with the way mapped types work. Mapped types iterate over the members of a `union` not an intersection. Generally we can make the compiler iterate over the members of a union ( using mapped and conditional types). Intersection types are more like a cake.. once you put in the ingredient you can't take the eggs back out :)